# AutoMapper - Map a complex object to list of flat objects

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I map a complex object to a list of flat objects using the AutoMapper?
I want to convert list of fields to another list of objects keeping symbol as well.
I've tried to use `ITypeConverter` from the AutoMapper documentation, but still not worked.

```cs
public class Source
{
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }
    public Records Records { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
}

public class Records
{
    public List<Record> Record { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string RequestedSymbols { get; set; }
    public string RequestedFields { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
    public string Req_sym { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Stale { get; set; }
}
```

Consider a complex object:

```
{
  "Request": {
    "RequestedSymbols": "ABC,BCD,CDE",
    "RequestedFields": "ASK,BID,LAST",
    "Host": "XYZ",
    "Id": "123"
  },
  "Error": {
    "Code": "0",
    "Description": ""
  },
  "Records": {
    "Record": [
      {
        "Fields": {
          "Field": [
            {
              "Id": "200",
              "Name": "ASK",
              "Value": "43.75"
            },
            {
              "Id": "100",
              "Name": "BID",
              "Value": "43.73"
            },
            {
              "Id": "300",
              "Name": "LAST",
              "Value": "43.73"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Req_sym": "ABC",
        "Key": "ABC",
        "Stale": ""
      },
      {
        "Fields": {
          "Field": [
            {
              "Id": "200",
              "Name": "ASK",
              "Value": "76.18"
            },
            {
              "Id": "100",
              "Name": "BID",
              "Value": "76.17"
            },
            {
              "Id": "300",
              "Name": "LAST",
              "Value": "76.19"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Req_sym": "BCD",
        "Key": "BCD",
        "Stale": ""
      },
      {
        "Fields": {
          "Field": [
            {
              "Id": "200",
              "Name": "ASK",
              "Value": "16.34"
            },
            {
              "Id": "100",
              "Name": "BID",
              "Value": "16.33"
            },
            {
              "Id": "300",
              "Name": "LAST",
              "Value": "16.33"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Req_sym": "CDE",
        "Key": "CDE",
        "Stale": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "Service": "XYZ"
}
```

So, I expect convert to a list of objects like:

Destination:

```
[
  {
    "Symbol": "ABC",
    "ASK": 43.75,
    "BID": 43.73,
    "LAST": 43.73 
  },
  {
    "Symbol": "BCD",
    "ASK": 76.18,
    "BID": 76.17,
    "LAST": 76.19  
  },
  {
    "Symbol": "CDE",
    "ASK": 16.34,
    "BID": 16.33,
    "LAST": 16.33  
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please include the `ITypeConverter` code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Challenging yet interesting question.*

From my perspective, I would extract the object from the list and convert it into the `Dictionary`.

With the AutoMapper tools, you need these two concepts:

- Convert from Dictionary to concrete object. Reference: [Dynamic and ExpandoObject Mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html#dynamic-and-expandoobject-mapping)
- A custom type converter to convert from `Source` class to `List<Destination>` . Reference: [Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)

```cs
public class SourceToListDestinationTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Source, List<Destination>>
{
    public List<Destination> Convert(Source source, List<Destination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<Destination> result = new List<Destination>();
                              
        foreach (var record in source.Records.Record)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> fieldDict = record.Fields.Field
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (object)x.Value);

            fieldDict.Add(nameof(Destination.Symbol), record.Req_sym);

            result.Add(context.Mapper.Map<Destination>(fieldDict));
        }
                                
        return result;
    }
}
```

Your MappingConfiguration or Mapping Profile should be looked as below:

```cs
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
{       
    config.CreateMap<Source, List<Destination>>()
        .ConvertUsing<SourceToListDestinationTypeConverter>();
});
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ogOiH0)

Comment: `CreateMap<Source, List<Destination>>().ConvertUsing((s, context)=>context.Mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(s.Records))` would get rid of that `foreach`.